# Sending commands to Arduino while it's already running

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

I'm currently making a robot and I'm using Raspberry pi 3 and Arduino uno for it.

What I want to do is send commands to Arduino via Pi by using  a command line app (written in C)which takes in user input to make certain parts of the robot to move.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following programs to send and receive serial data from Arduino:

[Original Source](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/718340/C-program-to-Linux-Serial-port-read-write)

**SEND.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




#define BAUDRATE B115200 //Baud Rate Here
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0" //Serial Port Here
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

FILE *file;
int fileLen;
char *tmpbuffer;
void openport(void);
void readport(void);
void sendport(void);
int fd=0;
struct termios oldtp, newtp;
//char sendcmd1[256]="\0";
char buffer[512];

void main()
{


    openport();
    sleep(1);
//  readport();
    sendport();




}

void sendport(void)
{
        printf("enter write\n");
        int n;
     //   sem_wait(&len);
                file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

                //get file size

                fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
                fileLen = ftell(file);
                fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

                tmpbuffer = (char *)malloc(fileLen + 1);

                //read file contents
                printf("Start send\n");
                fread(tmpbuffer, fileLen, 1, file);
                fclose(file);

                n = write(fd, tmpbuffer, fileLen + 1);

                if (n < 0)
                {
                        fputs("write() of bytes failed!\n", stderr);
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("File sent successfully %d\n",n);
                }
                close(fd);

}

void openport(void)
{
         fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY |O_NDELAY );
    printf("Oviya %d\n",fd);
         if (fd <0)
         {
         perror(MODEMDEVICE);         }

         fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,0);
        tcgetattr(fd,&oldtp); /* save current serial port settings */
        // tcgetattr(fd,&newtp); /* save current serial port settings */
         bzero(&newtp, sizeof(newtp));
        // bzero(&oldtp, sizeof(oldtp));

         newtp.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

         newtp.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;

         newtp.c_oflag = 0;

         newtp.c_lflag = ICANON;

         newtp.c_cc[VINTR]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-c */
         newtp.c_cc[VQUIT]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-\ */
         newtp.c_cc[VERASE]   = 0;     /* del */
         newtp.c_cc[VKILL]    = 0;     /* @ */
         //newtp.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;     /* Ctrl-d */
         newtp.c_cc[VEOF]     = 0;     /* Ctrl-d */
         newtp.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;     /* inter-character timer unused */
         newtp.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;     /* blocking read until 1 character arrives */
         newtp.c_cc[VSWTC]    = 0;     /* '\0' */
         newtp.c_cc[VSTART]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-q */
         newtp.c_cc[VSTOP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-s */
         newtp.c_cc[VSUSP]    = 0;     /* Ctrl-z */
         newtp.c_cc[VEOL]     = 0;     /* '\0' */
         newtp.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;     /* Ctrl-r */
         newtp.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;     /* Ctrl-u */
         newtp.c_cc[VWERASE]  = 0;     /* Ctrl-w */
         newtp.c_cc[VLNEXT]   = 0;     /* Ctrl-v */
         newtp.c_cc[VEOL2]    = 0;     /* '\0' */


   //     tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
//  tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtp);
}
```

Go through the code and modify it according to your will.
This code expects a .txt file as input.

This answer is written from https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/718340/C-program-to-Linux-Serial-port-read-write

Visit the original site for additional information